# How can I change the style of a KOMA ToC for some parts of the document?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

In my document I have to "sections" for which I would like to have a different appearence in the table of contents.
The first "section" should have a skip between the `section`-entries, but in the second "section" the `section`-entries should have no vertical space (e.g. `tocbeforeskip=0ex`), bfseries and normalsize.

But applying e.g.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocbeforeskip=0ex,
]{section}
```

before the `chapter`-entry has no effect on the `section`-entries:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotoc,% switch on extended optional argument parsing
]{scrbook}

% ==== TOC style
\newcommand\tocgobble[1]{}% <- added
\newcommand\tocpageseparator{\normalsize\bfseries\,\mbox{---}\,}
\newcommand\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}% <- added
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}


\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\tocpageseparator,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox,% <- added
  % tocpagenumberformat=\textsf,
  beforeskip= 0ex,
  afterskip= 0.01ex
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}


\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocbeforeskip=2ex,
  tocentryformat=\bfseries\large,
]{section}


% no page number for chapters in TOC
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\tocgobble,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocgobble,% <- added
  % tocpagenumberformat=\textsf,
  beforeskip= 0ex,
  afterskip=0.1ex,
    tocentryformat=\bfseries\Large\sffamily,
]{chapter}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}

\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}

% ===============================
% Change style of TOC from here on.
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocbeforeskip=0ex,
]{section}
%===============================
\chapter{Projects}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I would not recommend to use different format settings for the section level in TOC.

But it is possible:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocbeforeskip=0ex,
    tocentryformat=\bfseries\normalsize
  ]{section}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotoc,% switch on extended optional argument parsing
]{scrbook}

% ==== TOC style
\newcommand\tocgobble[1]{}% <- added
\newcommand\tocpageseparator{\normalsize\bfseries\,\mbox{---}\,}
\newcommand\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}% <- added
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}


\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\tocpageseparator,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox,% <- added
  % tocpagenumberformat=\textsf,
  beforeskip= 0ex,
  afterskip= 0.01ex
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}


\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocbeforeskip=2ex,
  tocentryformat=\bfseries\large,
]{section}


% no page number for chapters in TOC
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\tocgobble,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocgobble,% <- added
  % tocpagenumberformat=\textsf,
  beforeskip= 0ex,
  afterskip=0.1ex,
    tocentryformat=\bfseries\Large\sffamily,
]{chapter}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}

\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}
\subsection{FooBar}

% ===============================
% Change style of TOC from here on. (not recommended)
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocbeforeskip=0ex,
    tocentryformat=\bfseries\normalsize
  ]{section}%
}
%===============================
\chapter{Projects}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]